# More efficient solution to check expression syntaxt?

Tags: java

**Problem:** is the expression syntax correct?

**Rules:** goes from left to right numbers of left and right brackets should be the same, and open-close in good convention, first left, example:

```
(xxx(xx)())          - OK
((()))               - OK
(x(x(x(x(x))X)x)x)   - OK
(()()                - WRONG
)()                  - WRONG
```

My solution:

```
private boolean syntaxValidator(String str) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(str)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == '(') {
                counter++;
            } else if (str.charAt(i) == ')') {
                counter--;
                if (counter < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (counter == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it effective? Can it be solved by using regular expression? How?

Comment: Note that `if (counter == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }` could be replaced by `return counter == 0;`

Comment: This should probably go to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can't solve this problem using a classical regular expression as this is not a regular grammar. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex wouldn't cut it, your solution seems fine. For a bit more efficiency, do this (this is not the entire code, but just a snippet):

```
int strLength = str.length(); // so you don't have to call this method every time

for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i); // so you won't have to call this twice
    if (ch == '(') {
        counter++;
    } else if (ch == ')') {
        counter--;
        if (counter < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The suggestion re `return counter == 0;` in comments above is also great.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it effective?

Yes, in my opinion, provided you incorporate the advice in the other answer.Typically how this is done for validating multiple types of brackets is by using a stack. Push a character on the top of the character, if it is an opening bracket kind of character (one of `(`, `[`, `{` ). While encountered a closing kind of character (`)`, `}`, `]` ), pop the stack and compare the current and the popped character. If no equal, then you have a syntax error.

> Can it be solved by using regular expression?

This is not a job of regex. Bracket validation would typically require you to have some kind of count (like you are doing now). Regex by nature does not maintain any count at all. Although, I think, this is possible by using PCRE, I do not remember  it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't solve it with regular expressions. You need at least context free parser to do it.

In a context free grammar you can write

```
N = '(' M ')'
```

In regular expressions this is not allowed. This restriction allows much quicker matching compared to context free grammars.

See this for details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar